# How can I feed a mysql database with a XHTML table, or filter this table any other way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have to work with a third party database which doesn't allow the kind of requests and filters I need to use on it.

It possesses a very basic API to request broad datas from it, which returns the datas as an XHTML form (which is, in fact a `<table>` with `<th>` column titles and unlabeled `<td>` cells).

What I need is a way to filter the content of this table, with various criteria that I can't put in the original request through the API.

So I have to turn my XHTML table into a mySQL table of some sort, in order to make specific requests on it.

What I imagine would work this way :

1. Web app is opened
2. It requests the fresh datas from the third party database
3. Get the XHTML table as a result
4. Works some parsing magic on it
5. Shove it into my MySQL database (truncate and update a table wich replicate the `<table>` structure)
6. Let me request however I want my own mirror database

I wondering if this is the simplest way of doing it, and if so how best should I proceed to do it ?

Should I parse the XHTML table to make it SQL-ready ? If so, how ?
Or parse and insert it line by line, but then how should I transform my table into an array of lines ?

Or is there some magical way to do a "SELECT x FROM `<table>` WHERE `<column>` = `<value>` AND `<other stuff>`" on a XHTML table directly ?

Any advice appreciated !

Comment: Can you provide an input example?

Comment: ...If it is valid XHTML then it should also be a valid XML document. There are a few tools to convert XML to JSON, which much more handy to work with...

I was recently searching for that, and the best spec I found was http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html.

In the author's blog there is a synchronous implementation (which I didn't tested) and, as I understand, should be enough for you.

In my case, I needed an asynchronous parser so I implemented my own one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xs2jiter

Comment: There is much more columns, but for readability, here is an exact input for 3 columns, 2 lines :

`<table>
<tr>
<th>ID<th>
<th>NAME</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>DV0006</td>
<td>Smith</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>DV0007</td>
<td>Anderson</td>
</tr>

</table>`

And so forth...

if I had a <td name=value>Name</td> structure, I would be able to make some selections based on my colums titles with classic XML manipulations.

But it's a rudimentary encoded XML result, wich is more a bare-bones HTML table than a proper XML file.